# Definition (and differences) between robotic platform and semirobotic platform

Tags: platform

I'm looking for the definitions (and the diferences) of robotic platform and semirobotic platform. Online it's quite impossible to find them. Can you share your knowledge and suggest me a good source please?

Comment: are you certain that `semirobotic platform` is the correct term?

Comment: Hello @jsotola yes, you can find it in many books: https://www.google.com/search?q=semi-robotic+platform&biw=1639&bih=764&tbs=bkt%3Ab%2Cbkv%3Ap&tbm=bks&sxsrf=APq-WBtNFBkSQsF3Sy1V7K7pTfZDnP9Rdg%3A1646030259497&ei=s20cYuPiHZSC9u8P6cqg4AU&ved=0ahUKEwijiKDH5KH2AhUUgf0HHWklCFwQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=semi-robotic+platform&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEANQ3A5Y3A5g7xFoAHAAeACAAWCIAbgBkgEBMpgBAKABAcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz-books